# Need help on cuting the entire row using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

i have a file with below lines

abc    abc.domain.com

123    123.domain.com

xyz    xyz.domain.com

I want to copy all domain.com lines to copy and paste is somewhere in excel.

like this

abc.domain.com

123.domain.com

xyz.domain.com

Please help me how to do this

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked, actually this simple question for you, but this is the first time am using.

Answer (score 0):

Nagaraju, you are not really asking a question about Notepad++, although you think you are.  What you are really asking a question about is How to Google.

By typing "notepad++ regexp substitution" into the Google machine found here:  www.google.com; I was able to find a list of websites which detail the process you are after.  I am leaving this as an exercise for the reader (you) to actually do in order to find the answer you are looking for.

Additionally, I used the Google machine to learn about macro's: http://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2013/10/27/notepad-macros-a-basic-example/

another very useful feature in a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple

1. Hold Alt or Alt + Shift key
2. Select the entire second column using mouse
3. Copy the selection (Ctrl-c)
4. Paste (Ctrl-v)